# Remove /index.php/ part of CodeIgniter URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I tried to get rid of "index.php" in url using the following rewrite code.but it's not working
please help me to fix this bug

```
# Development
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mvcTestApp/blog/ciBlog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|scripts|styles|vendor|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you post the Apache access/error log as well or at least tell what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This htaccess is working for me.Try this.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

In .htaccess file, add the following.

```
#Rewrite index.php
#Start using rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
#Rewrite condition
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#Whenever index.php is there in the url, it will rewrite to / automatically
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Check this link for more detail: http://subhra.me/remove-index-php-urls-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

**Use this rule**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

missing `"/"` before "index.php" in last rule

**or refer URL**

> http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suite of rewrite rules for CodeIgniter. Please read the inline comments:

```bsh
## Rewrite rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Remove the "index.php" part of URI
    # Remove access to "codeigniter" and "data" folders
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(codeigniter|data).*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with
    # a period. e.g. .git, .svn
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

    # WWW redirect
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.).*
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!dev\.).*
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the root index.php.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```